# MIPSで乗算のコードを書きましたが動きません。どうすればいいでしょうか？

Tags: assembly, mips

MIPSのアセンブリコードで乗算を行おうとしています。（下に書いてありますコードです）
ただQtspimを用いて動作が確認できませんでした。
何か対処法はありますでしょうか？

```
    .data
    str:
    .asciiz "\nEnter two positive integer a,b "
    .text
    .globl main
main:
    addi $sp,$sp,-16 #スタック上で4語分のスペースを取る
    sw $s0,12($sp) #$s0を退避する
    sw $s1,8($sp) #$s1を退避する
    sw $s2,4($sp) #$s2を退避する
    sw $ra,0($sp) #$raを退避する
    add $s0,$zero,$zero #$s0 = 0
L1:
    li $v0,4 #print_stringのシステムコールコード4を$v0にロード
    la $a0,str #asciizで保存した文字列のアドレスを$a0に格納
    syscall #実行

    li $v0,5 #read_intのシステムコード5を$s1にロード
    syscall #実行
    add $a1,$zero,$v0
    add $s1,$zero,$v0

    li $v0,5 #read_intのシステムコード5を$s2にロード
    syscall #実行
    add $a2,$zero,$v0
    add $s2,$zero,$v0

    jal multp #multへジャンプする
    j L1 #L1へジャンプする
End:
multp:
    beq $t0,$zero,end2 #$t0 ≠ 0 ならラベルendに行く
    add $s0,$s0,$s2 #r = r + y
    addi $t1,$zero,1 #$t1 = 1
    beq $s1,$t1,end1 #$s1 = 1ならラベルend1に行く
end1:
    lw $ra,0($sp) #$raを戻す
    lw $s2,4($sp) #$s2を戻す
    lw $s1,8($sp) #$s1を戻す
    lw $s0,12($sp) #$s0を戻す
    add $v0,$s0,$zero #$v0 = $s0
end2:
    jal half #halfへジャンプ
    add $s2,$s2,$s2 #$s2 = $s2 + $s2
    lw $ra,0($sp) #$raを戻す
    lw $s2,4($sp) #$s2を戻す
    lw $s1,8($sp) #$s1を戻す
    lw $s0,12($sp) #$s0を戻す
    j $ra
odd:
    andi $t0,$s0,0x1 #$t0 = $s0 & 0x1
    jr $ra
half:
srl $s1,$s1,1 #$s1を右に1シフト
    jr $ra
```

Comment: `beq $t0,$zero,end2 #$t0 ≠ 0 ならラベルendに行く` の部分ですが、コメントの内容が正しいのだとすれば、`beq` ではなく `bne`(Branch on Not Equal) ではないでしょうか。

Comment: そうでした！ありがとうございます。

Comment: ただQtspimを用いるとPCのアドレス0において例外が発生しましたなどと表示されうまく動作していないのです。

Comment: 後のご質問にコメントした通り(そちらの質問の方はご自身で削除してもらった方が良いと思います)なのですが、1点1点を全部コメントで明らかにしてもらおうとすると、とんでもない長大な「議論」になってしまいそうです。なぜこのようなコードが得られたのですか。ネットのどこかからコードを持ってきたのでしょうか?それとも設問(夏休みの宿題?)に何らかのヒントがついていたのでしょうか?[さらに前のご質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/47290/13972)との関係は?(サブルーチン`odd`はC++関数`odd`をアセンブリ化したものに見えます。)せめてそこら辺の情報を明らかにすることはできませんか?

Comment: ちなみに現在のコードで`beq`を`bne`に変更しても何の意味もありません。比較対象となっているレジスタ`$t0`に値を設定するようなコードが全く実行されないからです。